# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error upon deleting document and executing post middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose, axios

I have a problem related to, most likely, double execution of the delete query on a document. My suspicion is the issue lies in the middleware executing after deleting the document, could that be the case? **The error I get says**:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header
...
```

**Axios call on frontend:**

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/columns/delete/${columnId}`, {   
      headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      }
}).then(() => {
      dispatch({type: ActionTypes.DeleteColumn, payload: columnId})
}).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
});
```

**Mongoose method on backend:**

```
export const deleteColumn = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
      try {
            await Column.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.columnId);
            res.json();
      } catch(err) {
            res.status(404).json({message: "Column not found"});
            throw new Error('Column not found');
      }
});
```

**Finally, the middleware that clears all the child elements in a cascade:**

```
columnSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function(res) {
      const columnId = res._id;
      const childIssues = await Issue.find({columnId: columnId});

      // array of promises is passed to Promise.all to resolve concurrently
      Promise.all(
            childIssues.map(async column => {
                  await Issue.findByIdAndDelete(column._id)
            })
      );
});
```

I know this code is far from perfect, especially the middleware part. I'm still learning the related concepts and I find it particularly hard to wrap my head around asynchrounous calls, so I will be more than happy for any feedback and help.

Comment: Still facing this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have moved it for things to tackle down in the future but I'm more than willing to go back to it if there was any new anchor point for troubleshooting